# Where are details regarding peripheral configuration for STM32 controllers in datasheets?

Tags: arm, stm32, datasheet, configuration

I have recently begun working more with STM32 processors coming from the more simple Atmel 8bit variety. The Atmel datasheets are very nicely laid out -- specifically speaking to how they provide information relating to hardware configuration registers.

[image]

However, I am having a difficult time finding similar information in the ST datasheets. How, for example, do I find information about configuring the alternative options on a pin, or the sampling rate of the ADC? I can find only general information about this hardware for a given processor, but never as much detail as provided by Atmel shown above.

Am I just looking at a condensed datasheet? I pulled one available directly from mouser: see an [example](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/DM00039193-490390.pdf).

Comment: Go to the ST site, and you will find a page similar to this: http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1295/LN1808/PF259971# which will have all sorts of technical documentation. If it exists it is probably on the ST site. edit - hit the design resources tab, forgot that it doesn't link to the tab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the detailed info including register map and other register details for an ST microcontroller, you want what they call the *reference manual*, not the datasheet or the user manual.

See for example:

- [Reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf) for STM32F405/415, STM32F407/417, STM32F427/437 and
  STM32F429/439 lines
- [Reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031936.pdf) for STM32F0x1/STM32F0x2/STM32F0x8  lines
- [Reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00096844.pdf) for STM32F401xB/C and STM32F401xD/E lines
- [Reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00246267.pdf) for STM32F100xx line

Comment: Yes, I too was looking at the condensed datasheet.  Not be confused, ST of course calls it the "reference manual".